# Meaning of symbols like $\inf\limits_{\epsilon>0}$

Tags: soft-question, notation, supremum-and-infimum

I am very confused at the precise definition of the following symbols. A reference or explanation would be great.

$$\Large\inf\limits_{\epsilon>0}\qquad \sup\limits_{\epsilon>0}$$

Comment: [Here you go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum).

Comment: Does the set $(0,1)$ (that is, the set of real numbers between 0 and 1 exclusive) have a minimum (smallest element)? No. ($0$ doesn't count because $0$ isn't in $(0,1)$.) However, it's _infimum_ is $0$.

Answer (score 4):

For example, for $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ we have
$$ \inf_{\epsilon > 0} f(\epsilon) = \inf \{ f(\epsilon) \mid \epsilon > 0 \}, $$
where $\inf$ means the infimum of a real subset, that is, the greatest lower bound of that subset. $\sup$ means the supremum, that is the least upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

another  definition of sup and inf:
Let say X is set

$$supX=\alpha \\ 1.\forall x\epsilon X,\quad x\le \alpha \\ 2.\quad \varepsilon >0,\quad x>\alpha -\varepsilon    $$

and

$$\\ infX=\beta \\ 1.\forall x\epsilon X,\quad x\ge \beta \\ 2.\quad \varepsilon >0,\quad x<\beta +\varepsilon   $$

Comment: @Meelo,edited,thanks)